# Needle in haystack function not working correctly (offset issue)

Tags: php

Here I got this function:

```
public function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset) {
        $chr = array();
        foreach($needles as $needle) {
                $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
                if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
        }
        if(empty($chr)) return false;
        return min($chr);
}
```

And this one:

```
   function usernameCurseWords($name) {
      $string = $name;
      $array  = array('bad', 'words', 'are', 'here');

      if (parent::strposa($string, $array, 0)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
```

and I call it like this:

```
if ($this->usernameCurseWords($username)) { throw new Exception($error['userCurseWords']); }
```

If the haystack is "1bad", then the function will return true ("bad" is a needle).

If however the haystack is "badblablbla", then the function returns false.

Any idea why this doesn't work correctly?

Comment: I also tried without offset anywhere, still the same.

Comment: Since it doesn't seem to matter what you return as long as you return something then return either true or false instead of `min($chr)`.  I believe you're returning 0 in your case which would evaluate to false in `parent::strposa($string, $array, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, that indeed fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know strpos will **Returns the position of where the needle exists** relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

So if your string found at 0 position than it will return zero.

but in your usernameCurseWords() it is in if condition so.

if position is found at zero position then it will treat as false;
got my point.

```
echo strpos('badall', 'bad',0);
```

will return 0. b/c position found at 0 position.

```
echo strpos('1badall', 'bad',0);
```

will return 1 b/c position found at 1 position.

```
if (parent::strposa($string, $array, 0)) {
     return true;
  }
```

but this line will only accept if return is 1.
so change your code according to that.

```
if (parent::strposa($string, $array, 0) !== false) {
     return true;
  }
```

// try a type matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, now I understand fully, which is the most important part.

As for the code, I am now simply returning true instead of min($chr) (which was resulting the 0 causing the issue). Code is also simpler for the use it has.

Answer (score 0):

```
!== FALSE ... and 0 is not the same, FALSE is boolean, 0 (zero) not
```

so just use

```
!=
```

Comment: I made that change, and the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
if(empty($chr)) return false;

empty(0) = true
So when the offset is zero, you'll get true

Comment: However if it returns true, it means it found a bad word / needle in the haystack. But in this problem, if the needle was at the very start of the haystack, it doesn't even return true, offset being 0.